# Type Error in .then function using Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, typeerror

I have a get request that detects if user is Admin or not.
My problem is that I want to display a button using `v-if` to check if it's true or false. By default the value is set to `false`.

**Data**

[image]

**Then we got the button** :

[image]

**And the `.then` in `beforeCreate`** :

[image]

Comment: My problem is that I got this Type Error telling me that `Cannot set property 'isAdmin' of undefined` And the button does not show or hide if userIsAdmin. Sorry, I try to be as much clear as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) to preserve the `this` context:

```js
.then((responses) => {
```

Otherwise the callback function injects its own `this`